# How to type hinting of multi-indexed pandas dataframe, Python3.8+?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

The column of the dataframe `df` is multi-indexed.

```
>>>df
    c1      c2    
    d1  d2  d1  d2
r1  11  12  21  22
```

Therefore, with the code `list(df.columns.levels[0]` a `list` of `['c1', 'c2']` is created. The following code can run without error. But PyCharm marks `levels` in the line `print(list(df.columns.levels[0]))` as a warning `Unresolved attribute reference 'levels' for class 'Index'`.

I think it could be solved by more specific type hinting in the function signature of `print_columns`. In the code below, I only use the type `df: pd.DataFrame`. PyCharm thinks it is a simple dataframe without multi-index.

Could you please show me how to improve the type hint? Or do you have other solutions to remove the warning from PyCharm?

Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd


def get_df() -> pd.DataFrame:
    data = {
        ('c1', 'd1'): [11],
        ('c1', 'd2'): [12],
        ('c2', 'd1'): [21],
        ('c2', 'd2'): [22],
    }

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
    df.index = ['r1']
    return df


def print_columns(df: pd.DataFrame):
    print(list(df.columns.levels[0]))  # prints ['c1', 'c2']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df_ = get_df()
    print_columns(df=df_)
```